# Reset countdown timer value to the default value saved in the Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, timer

I am creating a countdown timer from a default Int value in the array, but I cannot figure out how to reset the timer to the original value in the array. Thats means when the user press "Stop Brewing" the countdown timer will restart from 5 minutes for example. Can someone help me to find out what I am doing wrong or missing? I am doing my first steps into iOS development.

Thanks in advance!

My code:

```
@objc func runTimer() {

    cafe.time -= 1
    labelCowntdownTimer.text = "\(cafe.time)"
    // MM:SS:_

    let flooredCounter = cafe.time

    let minute = (flooredCounter % 3600) / 60
    var minuteString = "\(minute)"
    if minute < 10 {
        minuteString = "0\(minute)"
    }

    let second = (flooredCounter % 3600) % 60
    var secondString  = "\(second)"
    if second < 10 {
        secondString = "0\(second)"
    }

    labelCowntdownTimer.text = "\(minuteString):\(secondString)"

}

//Mark: - resetTimer

@objc func resetTimer() {

    timer.invalidate()
    //cafe.time
    runTimer()

}


//Mark: - ButtonPressed - Start Timer

@IBAction func startButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if !isTimerRunning {

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(runTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        isTimerRunning = true
        startButton.setTitle("Stop Brewing", for: .normal)
    } else {
        resetTimer()
        isTimerRunning = false
        startButton.setTitle("Start Brewing", for: .normal)

    }
}
```

Comment: what is `cafe.time` do you want to reset it too?

Comment: Cafe(name: "Arabica", time: 300, temperature: "90") that would be an example of my array.

Comment: and you want to set the time to zero. right /?

Comment: no, basically when the user press the stop button. The time should restart to the original value from the Array (300 in the example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `viewDidload()` or whenever you get the value stored in your array, store the value in a variable.

```
var initialValueOfTime = 0   // the initial value is stored here. which is 300

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initialValueOfTime = cafe.time
}
@objc func runTimer() {

    if isTimerRunning {
        cafe.time -= 1
    } else {
        cafe.time = initialValueOfTime
    }
    labelCowntdownTimer.text = "\(cafe.time)"
    // MM:SS:_

    let flooredCounter = cafe.time

    let minute = (flooredCounter % 3600) / 60
    var minuteString = "\(minute)"
    if minute < 10 {
        minuteString = "0\(minute)"
    }

    let second = (flooredCounter % 3600) % 60
    var secondString  = "\(second)"
    if second < 10 {
        secondString = "0\(second)"
    }

    labelCowntdownTimer.text = "\(minuteString):\(secondString)"

}

//Mark: - resetTimer

@objc func resetTimer() {

    timer.invalidate()
    runTimer()
}


//Mark: - ButtonPressed - Start Timer

@IBAction func startButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if !isTimerRunning {
        isTimerRunning = true
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(runTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startButton.setTitle("Stop Brewing", for: .normal)
    } else {
        isTimerRunning = false
        resetTimer()
        startButton.setTitle("Star Brewing", for: .normal)

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried a similar way as well but will result in a error which is 'Cannot use instance member 'cafe' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available'

Comment: @MiguelP. thats why i said to assign the value in viewDidLoad. check my updated code

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
@objc func resetTimer() {

    timer.invalidate()
    timer = nil //You should also need to nil to a timer to stop it.

    //runTimer() - also comment this line as its not needed to call this function after stop timer.

    //Reinitialize all your required variable here to calculate the time
}
```